# Concatenate column values to single row in visualization

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have this table in Power BI, where the visible rows all have the same tracking number, but there are multiple rows due to the `sku` column.

[image]

How can I achieve a result like this where this is shown in just one row, and all `sku`s are listed comma separated:

[image]

I have achieved this using pandas, but want to do the same in Power BI. However, I have not been able to find a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `CONCATENATEX` evaluating the list of SKU for that row in your visualization. You measure will need to look something like this:

```
skus =
CONCATENATEX (
    VALUES ( 'Table'[sku] ), 
    [sku],
    ","
)
```

Comment: Instead of using `VALUES( 'Table'[quantity] )` use `CONCATENATEX ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Quantity] , ", " ) `